# How can I determine whether it's faster to face an object rotating clockwise or counter clockwise?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, trigonometry

I've been trying this to no avail for some days now, but basically I have some creatures and the player on the screen. What I want to happen is for the enemies to turn to face the player at a variable speed, rather than 'lock' into position and face the player immediately.

What I am trying to do is work out whether it is faster for a given enemy to rotate clockwise or counter clockwise to face the player, but it's proving to be beyond my capabilities with trigonometry.

Example:

[image]

`x` in these figures represents the 'shorter' path and the direction I want to rotate in each situation.

What is the simplest way to work out either 'clockwise' or 'counter-clockwise' in this situation, using any of the following:

- The direction the enemy is facing.
- The angle between the enemy to the player, and player to the enemy.

Comment: It's not really clear why, given the values of x and y, you can't determine the correct direction of rotation. It would seem to be as simple as: pick the smaller one and go that way. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I guess I'm struggling with the part where you work out what 'way' the smaller one is; whether it's clockwise or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're computing them, but isn't one negative and one positive? Or, if they're not -- if you're calculating these two angles such that both are positive -- you must know at the time of the calculation which one is clockwise.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ok it seems I may be having issues with actually getting x and y.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is **no need** to calculate angles or use trigonometric functions here, assuming you have a direction vector.

```
var pos_x, pos_y, dir_x, dir_y, target_x, target_y;
if ((pos_x - target_x) * dir_y > (pos_y - target_y) * dir_x) {
    // Target lies clockwise
} else {
    // Target lies anticlockwise
}
```

This simply draws an imaginary line through the object in the direction it's facing, and figures out which side of that line the target is on.  This is basic linear algebra, so you should not need to use `sin()` or `cos()` etc. anywhere in this function, unless you need to calculate the direction vector from the angle.

This also uses a right-handed coordinate system, it will be backwards if you are using a left-handed coordinate system -- the formulas will be the same, but "clockwise" and "anticlockwise" will be swapped.

**Deeper explanation:** The function computes the outer product of the forward vector `(dir_x, dir_y)` and the vector to the target, `(target_x - pos_x, target_y - pos_y)`.  The resulting outer product is a pseudoscalar which is positive or negative, depending on whether the target is clockwise or anticlockwise.

#### Crash course on vectors

A vector is a **magnitude** and **direction**, e.g., 3 km north, or 6 centimeters down.  You can represent a vector using **cartesian coordinates** (x, y), or you can represent it using **polar coordinates** (r,θ).  Both representations give you the *same* vectors, but they use different numbers and different formulas.  In general, you should stick with cartesian coordinates instead of polar coordinates.  If you're writing a game, polar coordinates suck royally — they litter your code with `sin()` and `cos()` everywhere.

The code has three vectors in it:

- The vector `(pos_x, pos_y)` is the position of the object, relative to the origin.
- The vector `(target_x, target_y)` is the position of the target, relative to the origin.
- The vector `(dir_x, dir_y)` is the direction that the object is facing.

Comment: Interesting, what are `dir_x` and `dir_y`?

Comment: The vector `(dir_x, dir_y)` is the direction that the object is facing.

Comment: Sorry, a lot of this stuff is nontrivial for me to get my head around. How do I calculate the dir_x and dir_y? I know how to get the angle between two things in radians but I'm not sure about how to get two separate values that represent which way something is facing.

Comment: You don't calculate direction.  You store it in your object: you need position and direction, right?

Comment: Wait, do you know what a vector is, conceptually?  In case you didn't know: a vector represents a **direction** and **magnitude**, e.g., 4 kilometers north, or six centimeters down.  You can represent a vector using **coordinates**, in 2D you usually use `(x,y)` coordinates.

Comment: You can also represent a vector in **polar coordinates**, e.g., (r,θ).  Any time you use (r,θ) polar coordinates instead of (x,y) cartesian coordinates you might have to do some trigonometry.  If you use (x,y) cartesian coordinates everywhere, you don't have to do as much math.  Probably.  There are exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So `dir_x` would be the horizontal distance and `dir_y` the vertical between each object right?

Comment: The vector `(dir_x, dir_y)` stores the direction that the object is facing.

Comment: If you keep splitting vectors into "horizontal" and "vertical" parts, you will find it very difficult to understand.  A vector is a single thing.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not understanding how to calculate the vector but I figure it will be worth my time to research that component of my problem rather than have you try and explain it to me. I understand what a vector is, I just don't know how to get the x and y values for it in this case.

Comment: You may want an introduction to elementary linear algebra.  If you do a little bit of vector math, everything will be much easier and you won't have to do much trig.

Comment: I'm still having trouble about why you would need to calculate direction, because if you don't have the direction stored somewhere, how do you know which way the object is facing?  The problem doesn't make any sense unless you already know what direction the object is facing.  Is it facing up?  Down?  Left?  Right?  etc.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The problem is that a game may just use `x, y, angle` for the position and "direction an object is facing." So saying "dir_x and dir_y" for angle may seem alien.

Comment: @STO: Feel free to ask a more specific question if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const CLOCKWISE:int = 0;
const COUNTER_CLOCKWISE:int = 1;
const PI2:Number = Math.PI * 2


function determineSmallestAngle(from:Sprite, to:Sprite):int
{
    var a1:Number = Math.atan2(to.y - from.y, to.x - from.x);
    var a2:Number = from.rotation * Math.PI / 180;

    a2 -= Math.floor(a2 / PI2) * PI2;

    if(a2 > Math.PI) a2 -= PI2;

    a2 -= a1;

    if (a2 > Math.PI) a2 -= PI2;
    if (a2 < -1 * Math.PI) a2 += PI2;

    if (a2 > 0) return CLOCKWISE;
    return COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;

}
```

Comment: This is the solution that I used, but the accepted answer is probably the right way to go about the problem if you understand the basic math involved. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you just need the direction, the above answer is better. If you need the exact angle, you might use this one. Thanks.